# resultado de subtração de numeros de 32 para 64

Tags: assembly

Estou aprender a programar em assembly e tenho um problema que e o seguinte:

Tenho um resultado de uma subtracção em numero de 32 bits, e tem que retornar um numero de 64 bits.

Nota: estou a usar uma vm de linux de 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.comm   diff64, 8, 8         # Declara simbolo de 64 bits

MOV EBX, 87654321            # Minuendo em EBX
MOV EAX, 12345678            # Subtraendo em EAX

SUB EBX, EAX                 # Subtrai EAX de EBX, resultado em EAX

MOV DWORD PTR diff64, EAX    # Preenche 32bits menos significativos do simbolo de 64bits
MOV DWORD PTR diff64 + 4, 0  # Preenche 32bits mais significativos do simbolo de 64bits
```